# mysqli Update with extra query

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli, sql-update

At first I have to enter two Accountnames in the website.

My tablename is 'account'.

The rows are id, username and recruiter.
The lines are
7, Janis, 0
 and
4, testlol, 0.

I want to 'connect' two users. 
In the first line - the line of Janis - have to change his 'recruiter' into the value of the other user.

So the result should looks like:

7 | Janis  | 4
and
4 | testlol | 7

...

In my php script I wrote

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql1 = "UPDATE account SET recruiter=??? WHERE username=\"" . $_POST["account1"] . "\"";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

What do I have to write instead of the ??? for updating it with the other user's id?

It's from this form:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" >
    <p>Account Nr.1:</p><input class="input" type="text" name="account1" value="">
    <p>Account Nr.2:</p><input class="input" type="text" name="account2" value="">
    <p></p><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Bestätigen"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Who is `the other user`? Shouldn't that just be the `???`? Don't pass user input directly to your query, separate it with prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand...
I only type two Accaountnames in my website. 
In the form they have the names 'account1' and 'account2'.
Helpful?

Comment: How is the `recruiter` determined? From a form value, a db value?

Comment: So the `recruiter` is account2? Just `$_POST["account2"]`, if that is correct.

Comment: My problem is, I want to change the 'recruiter' into the 'id' of the other user. So i have to call up the id with the username in my update script.
I think so...

Comment: Run a subquery in the update to pull the id.

Comment: Yeah .. but .. how do I do this?

Comment: I don't know your tables or columns how does `userid` correlate to `$_POST["account2"]`? Adding something like `(select userid from table where column = $_POST["account2"])` I think would do it. But again please **don't** do it this way, look at prepared statements.

Comment: but I can't write it that way in an update command...

Comment: Yes, you can. Follow my exact syntax.

Comment: I could write 
    UPDATE account 
    SET recruiter=(
    SELECT id FROM account 
    WHERE username = $_POST["account2"])
    WHERE username=$_POST["account1"];

Comment: Yes, can you not? Is userid not unique (1 id per table)? But again donttttt do it that way.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work...
They said:
"Error updating record: You can't specify target table 'account' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: my code is:

    "UPDATE account SET recruiter=(SELECT id FROM account WHERE username=\"" . $_POST["account2"] . "\") WHERE username=\"" . $_POST["account1"] . "\"";

Comment: DIdn't know it was the same table. See this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: I've had written the same code they said

    "update account set recruiter = (select id from account where username =\"" . $_POST["account2"] . "\") where username =\"" . $_POST["account1"] . "\"";


, but the error is still there

Comment: What, did you miss last comment?

Comment: the thread can't help me.
I tried it the same way they said...
I'm in a fix... :'D

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for below. Although, it's hard to tell from you post what exactly you want. If I'm following correctly, you want to switch the recruiter value to other recruiter? If so, this should work:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE account SET recruiter = $_POST["account2"] WHERE username = $_POST["account1"]";
```

Comment: I don't want to set the recruiter to the name of the other user.
So ... there, where you written "account2" have to be the "SELECT id FROM account WHERE username=$_POST["account2"]".. But I can't insert it this way

Comment: What do you want to update or switch out? The id, username or recruiter?

Comment: recruiter have to be updated. The new vale have to be the id of the the other user's entered name

Comment: So you want the id's to be switched between the two users?

Comment: No, the id's have to stay the same. Only the row 'recruiter' have to become the value of the 'id' of the other user.

So the recruiter of Janis have to change to 4 - the id of testlol
The recruiter of testlol have to change to 7 - the id of Janis

Comment: This is kind of confusing. Why are you trying to have the recruiter of one of them switch to the other's id number and vice versa? Can you explain what you are trying to do so I can get a better understanding to help you?